# Select rows that are indirectly referenced in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

**PREPARATION**

Consider this script to create a MySQL dummy-database:

```
CREATE SCHEMA `zzz_dummy` ;
CREATE TABLE `zzz_dummy`.`subtable2` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `col1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
CREATE TABLE `zzz_dummy`.`subtable1` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `ref_subtab2` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
CREATE TABLE `zzz_dummy`.`maintable` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `ref_subtab1` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

ALTER TABLE `zzz_dummy`.`maintable` 
ADD INDEX `fk_subtab1_idx` (`ref_subtab1` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `zzz_dummy`.`maintable` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_subtab1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`ref_subtab1`)
  REFERENCES `zzz_dummy`.`subtable1` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


ALTER TABLE `zzz_dummy`.`subtable1` 
ADD INDEX `fk_subtab2_idx` (`ref_subtab2` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `zzz_dummy`.`subtable1` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_subtab2`
  FOREIGN KEY (`ref_subtab2`)
  REFERENCES `zzz_dummy`.`subtable2` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

INSERT INTO zzz_dummy.subtable2 VALUES
  (1,'ref_val_1'),
  (2,'ref_val_2'),
  (3,'no_ref');

INSERT INTO zzz_dummy.subtable1 VALUES
  (1,'1'),
  (2,'2'),
  (3,'3');

INSERT INTO zzz_dummy.maintable VALUES
  (1,'1'),
  (2,'2'),
  (3,'1'),
  (4,'1'),
  (5,'2'),
  (6,'1');
```

This will produce the following tables and entries:

```
maintable:
+----+-------------+
| id | ref_subtab1 |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |
|  3 |           1 |
|  4 |           1 |
|  6 |           1 |
|  2 |           2 |
|  5 |           2 |
+----+-------------+

subtable1:
+----+-------------+
| id | ref_subtab2 |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |
|  2 |           2 |
|  3 |           3 |
+----+-------------+

subtable2:
+----+-----------+
| id | col1      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | ref_val_1 |
|  2 | ref_val_2 |
|  3 | no_ref    |
+----+-----------+
```

**PROBLEM**

As you can see, the column `ref_subtab1` in `maintable` references `id` in `subtable1`, which column `ref_subtab2` finally references `id` in `subtable2`. I want to select all rows in `subtable2` that are indirectly referenced in aforementioned manner.

I have tried

```
SELECT subtable2.* FROM zzz_dummy.subtable2
  INNER JOIN zzz_dummy.maintable
  INNER JOIN zzz_dummy.subtable1
  WHERE zzz_dummy.maintable.ref_subtab1=zzz_dummy.subtable1.id
    AND zzz_dummy.subtable1.ref_subtab2=zzz_dummy.subtable2.id;
```

but this returns 6 results, one for every match in `maintable`:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | col1      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | ref_val_1 |
|  1 | ref_val_1 |
|  1 | ref_val_1 |
|  1 | ref_val_1 |
|  2 | ref_val_2 |
|  2 | ref_val_2 |
+----+-----------+
```

I do not want redundant values, I would like it to return:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | col1      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | ref_val_1 |
|  2 | ref_val_2 |
+----+-----------+
```

Can this be done efficiently with a MySQL statement?

Comment: use `distinct`. you are getting redundant rows because of the one-many relationship.

Comment: @vkp Is my approach at least efficient or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented use `distinct` to get the unique result combination and also move those conditions from `WHERE` clause to `JOIN ON` condition like

```
SELECT distinct subtable2.* 
FROM zzz_dummy.subtable2
  INNER JOIN zzz_dummy.subtable1
  ON zzz_dummy.subtable1.ref_subtab2 = zzz_dummy.subtable2.id
  INNER JOIN zzz_dummy.maintable 
 ON zzz_dummy.maintable.ref_subtab1 = zzz_dummy.subtable1.id;
```